# Shell command that replaces event codes according to a dictionary

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep, cut

I've got a file (silly_log.txt) in which events are encoded with numeric values and I'd like to expand these codes to a form that can be read by humans more easily. The information that is required to accomplish this is in a different file (dictionary.txt). My situation looks something like this:

silly_log.txt (example):

```
0
1
5
0
1
7
1
5
0
```

dictionary.txt (example):

```
0:idle
1:receiving data
5:processing data
7:parity error
```

desired output:

```
0:idle
1:receiving data
5:processing data
0:idle
1:receiving data
7:parity error
1:receiving data
5:processing data
0:idle
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk, you can say:

```
awk -F':' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1":"a[$1]}' dictionary.txt silly_log.txt
```

which outputs:

```
0:idle
1:receiving data
5:processing data
0:idle
1:receiving data
7:parity error
1:receiving data
5:processing data
0:idle
```

- `-F':'` option sets the field separator to `':'`.
- `FNR==NR` matches if and only if the first argument file `dictionary.txt` is read, then it creates a map.
- The `{print ..}` fragment is executed while the second argument file is read, then it interprets the codes to the texts based on the map.

**EDIT**
As an alternative, you can also say just with bash:

```
declare -a a

while IFS=: read -r code str; do
    a["$code"]="$str"
done < "dictionary.txt"

while read -r code; do
    printf "%d:%s\n" "$code" "${a[$code]}"
done < "silly_log.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
/tmp> cat dictionary.txt
0:idle
1:receiving data
5:processing data
7:parity error
/tmp> cat silly.log
0
1
5
0
1
7
1
5
0
/tmp> perl -F: -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}=$F[1] if $ARGV eq "dictionary.txt"; print "$F[0]:$kv{$F[0]} " if $ARGV eq "silly.log" ' dictionary.txt silly.log
0:idle
1:receiving data
5:processing data
0:idle
1:receiving data
7:parity error
1:receiving data
5:processing data
0:idle
/tmp>
```